# SQL LEFT JOIN with WHERE and SUBSTR

Tags: sql, sas, left-join, where-clause, substr

I want to use SQL to left join two tables but only where the common column fits a substring criteria. How can this be accomplished?

```
CREATE TABLE MY_JOIN AS
    SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM DATA.TABLE_B AS B
LEFT JOIN DATA.TABLE_A AS A ON A.COMMON = B.COMMON
WHERE SUBSTR(A.COMMON,1,5) IN ('90210', '90211', '90212')
```

There are other questions that address using a left join with a where clause but do not specifically address using a substring function within the where clause.

Comment: You only want rows where `common` starts with one of the given strings? Or you want all rows, but only join the B rows when `common` starts with one of the given strings?

Comment: The first, where only `common` starts with one of the given strings in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply move the condition to the LEFT JOIN clause

```
CREATE TABLE MY_JOIN AS
    SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM DATA.TABLE_B AS B
LEFT JOIN DATA.TABLE_A AS A ON A.COMMON = B.COMMON 
                            and SUBSTR(A.COMMON,1,5) IN ('90210', '90211', '90212')
```

Comment: @adin: While this is a good answer on how to only outer join rows matching the given strings, you said in your request comments explicitly that this is what you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

In the request comments you have clarified that you only want to select rows that match the given strings. In that case apply the `SUBSTR` function on `b.common`, not `a.common`:

```
CREATE TABLE my_join AS
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM data.table_b AS b
LEFT JOIN data.table_a AS a ON a.common = b.common
WHERE SUBSTR(b.common, 1, 5) IN ('90210', '90211', '90212');
```